# Destructor of a class C with members of pointer C

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, tree

Assume the following class declaration:

```
class NTree
{
private:
    const T* fKey;
    NTree<T, N>* fNodes[N]; // N subtrees of degree N
    NTree();
...
}
```

in which we can add some fNodes, representing a subtree given an index. These will be dynamically allocated using `new`. However, there are elements which are static, and not dynamically allocated:

```
public:
    static NTree<T, N> NIL; // sentinel
...
```

We choose to allocate this on the stack using the default constructor supplied above.

```
template<class T, int N>
NTree<T, N> NTree<T, N>::NIL;
```

Now, let's say we wish to delete an NTree. The class NTree is recursive, having pointer to NTree inside it.
This is what I'm struggling with.

I understand the logic behind a destructor, if we have e.g.

```
class MyClass 
{
private:
    TypeA * myA;
    TypeB * myB;
    TypeC * myC;
...
}
```

We could use a destructor to prevent these pointers from dangling, or getting lost.

```
~MyClass()
{
    delete myA;
    delete myB;
    delete myC;
}
```

However, when it comes to a recursive class, I have no clue how to wrap my mind around this, how to understand deletion.

A simple thing to think of:

```
template<class T, int N>
NTree<T, N>::~NTree()
{
    delete[] fNodes;
}
```

However, it won't work, as some nodes are NIL (stack allocated), so deleting them will result in a crash.

Another idea is:

```
template<class T, int N>
NTree<T, N>::~NTree()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        delete fNodes[i];
    }
}
```

However, this will result in a stack overflow, because of the stack being bombarded with frames for each recursive call of `~NTree()`

And the following:

```
template<class T, int N>
NTree<T, N>::~NTree()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (fNodes[i] != &NIL)
            delete fNodes[i];
    }
}
```

Results in a read exception, because the recursive calls will deallocate fNodes[i] for a particular stack frame, thus trying to access that memory is invalid.

So my question is, how can I delete a member variable, where that member is recursively defined as the same class?

How can I make my destructor work?

**Edit: Attempt to provide more information without making it too convoluted**

I'm defining a destructor so it's probably wise to show  you my copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
template<class T, int N>
NTree<T, N> & NTree<T, N>::operator=(const NTree & aOtherNTree)
{
    //This is an already initialized object.
    if (this != &aOtherNTree)
    {
        fKey = aOtherNTree.fKey;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (fNodes[i] == &NIL)
                continue; //continue if nil

            delete fNodes[i]; //important -- so no dangling pointer
            fNodes[i] = new NTree<T, N>; //allocate memory
            fNodes[i] = aOtherNTree.fNodes[i]; //assign
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

..

```
template<class T, int N>
NTree<T, N>::NTree(const NTree & aOtherNTree)
{
    //This is a new object, nothing is initalized yet.
    fKey = aOtherNTree.fKey;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (fNodes[i] == &NIL)
            continue;

        fNodes[i] = new NTree<T, N>;
        fNodes[i] = aOtherNTree.fNodes[i];
    }
}
```

I hope this shows all instances of when I allocate memory that needs explicit deletion in the destructor.
NIL is a sentinel, we always assign a leaf to NIL.

This part is provided by the professor, it is where we set up the initial objects:

```
NS3Tree root(A);
root.attachNTree(0, *(new NS3Tree(A1)));
root.attachNTree(1, *(new NS3Tree(A2)));
root.attachNTree(2, *(new NS3Tree(A3)));
root[0].attachNTree(0, *(new NS3Tree(AA1)));
root[1].attachNTree(0, *(new NS3Tree(AB1)));
root[1].attachNTree(1, *(new NS3Tree(AB2)));
```

A1, A2, etc, are strings

Comment: `delete[] fNodes`  `fNodes` was not allocated with `new`, so you have no business to `delete` it. You may want to `delete` individual elements of the array, assuming *those* have been obtained with `new`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, yes. You're right. deleting fNodes definitely would not work, in that case. However, I show two methods in which I try to delete the elements of fNodes, as well, but without success.

Comment: Traverse the tree depth-first (using an explicit stack, not recursive calls). Delete nodes from the bottom up.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik alright, I'll try that. However the problem I anticipate is that using `delete` inside the destructor will automatically force recursion on it?

Comment: Not if the node you delete is a leaf node and doesn't have any children of its own.

Comment: " Results in a read exception, because the recursive calls will deallocate fNodes[i] for a particular stack frame, thus trying to access that memory is invalid." If you are getting an exception here, this is not beccause the destructor is written incorrectly, it's because you had some other error earlier.

Comment: "will result in a stack overflow" If your tree is too deep to be deleted recursively, how do you plan to process it?

Comment: @n.m. the class is given for a university homework project, so there must be a way to do it, I just have no idea how. Potentially fNodes is not allocated on the heap so that we learn some obscure way of deleting its members, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I was hoping the domain of this problem wasn't too specific, but alas it seems that way. :(

Comment: If this is a school project, then data sizes are likely small so stack overflow should not be an issue. Read errors should simply never occur. If you experience either then you have some other error unrelated to destruction. Show a [mcve].

Comment: "Potentially fNodes is not allocated on the heap so that we learn some obscure way of deleting" what's so obscure in `if (fNodes[i] != &NIL)`?

Comment: @n.m if we say that my destructor just above `Results in a read exception` is ok, and as you said `If you are getting an exception here, this is not beccause the destructor is written incorrectly, it's because you had some other error earlier`, then it must be in my copy constructor or assignment operator, but both of these yield proper output. Hence why I'm stumped. I have supplied both above.

Comment: 1. A static variable is not on the stack 2. Why not use NULL instead of Node::NIL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor and assignment operator are both totally wrong.

```
        if (fNodes[i] == &NIL)
            continue; //continue if nil
        delete fNodes[i]; //important -- so no dangling pointer
```

This is wrong logic. If your old child value was NIL, it will stay NIL forever, because it will be never assigned. This should be:

```
        if (fNodes[i] != &NIL)
            delete fnodes[i];
```

Of course in the copy ctor the above fragment should not appear, because fNodes[i] doesn't have any determined value. It should only appear in the assignment.

Now

```
        fNodes[i] = new NTree<T, N>; //allocate memory
        fNodes[i] = aOtherNTree.fNodes[i]; //assign
```

You allocate some node and then immediately overwrite a pointer to it with another pointer, managed by another node. The first assignment thus has no effect, except for a memory leak. The second one will result in an error later on. Here's a correct invocation

```
        if (aOtherNTree.fNodes[i] == &NIL)
            fNodes[i] = &NIL;
        else
            fNodes[i] = new NTree<T, N> (*aOtherNTree.fNodes[i]); // make a new copy
```

An alternative else clause is

```
        else {
            fNodes[i] = new NTree<T, N>;
            *fNodes[i] = *aOtherNTree.fNodes[i]); // assign the object, not the pointer
        }
```

I recommend writing a debugging function that would print a tree, including the address of each node. While debugging, print every tree you make to ensure no pointer sharing occurs.

Comment: That fixes it, thank you. Will accept. I guess going from a managed language to an unmanaged language has its difficulties. Anyway, your first statement about "This is wrong logic", I don't see how the two are any different, look at bit.ly/1OSwg4E - in the first instance, my code, I check if the node is equal to nil, if so, then continue, any statements below the continue won't be executed, therefore there is no functional difference between checking for nil and continuing, then when it is not true, we assign, versus checking for not nil, and when true, assigning.
Can you please explain?

Comment: I know I'm obviously wrong, But I would like to know why I am wrong.

Comment: @Kevin this is not the same code. You real code has statements in the loop body after the continue. This is where the difference lies. Continue will cause them to be skipped. You never want to skip them.